# Understanding the object returned by Model.find

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller

```
class DatasourcesController < ApplicationController
```

In that controller I have:

```
def show
  ....
  @datasource = DataSource.find(datasource_id)
  ...
end
```

In `datasource_helper.rb` I have:

```
  def datasource_type
    puts "\r\n\r\n::::::::::::\r\n ONCE AGAIN @datasource = #{@datasource.inspect}\r\n::::::::::::\r\n\r\n"
    # @datasource[:dsd_type_id] = "GOV"
    @datasource.partnertype.par_description
  end
```

Where

```
puts "\r\n\r\n::::::::::::\r\n ONCE AGAIN @datasource = #{@datasource.inspect}\r\n::::::::::::\r\n\r\n"
```

prints something like:

```
::::::::::::
 ONCE AGAIN @datasource = #<DataSource ....,  dsd_type_id: "XRPT", ...>
::::::::::::
```

And when this `@datasource.partnertype.par_description` is executed it produces query of this kind:

```
SELECT  `partnertype`.* FROM `partnertype` WHERE `partnertype`.`par_code` = 'XRPT' LIMIT 1
```

Can you explain me how this magic happens?
Where does `@datasource` methods come from? When I inspect it I see that it is Hash.
In other words what rules/conventions apply to this?
Is that mean that instance variable `@datasource` by default inherited all the methods form the corresponding  model?

Sorry but  I am new to rails all this implicit rules/conventions bug me a lot.

Comment: A lot of things in Rails seem like magic at first glance but really aren't. I recommend reading thru the guides, they really are good. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Comment: @Iceman I did, but didn't find the link.

Comment: "When I inspect it I see that it is Hash" - no, it isn't. Why do you think it's a hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` returns an object (check `@datasource.class`), but `inspect` prints it in a [friendly way](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-inspect).

In other words, `@datasource` "contains" an instance of your model's class (`DataSource`), which is a subclass of `ApplicationRecord`, which is a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base`, thats why you have all those methods.